# Modelling A Discrete-Time Time-Homogeneous Markov Chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

I am trying to compute the transition matrix for [this markov chain.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViPYg.png) I believe that I have done it correctly but the next section asks to diagonalise the matrix and it seems to be un-diagonisable.

`P1 <- matrix(c(0, 1/3, 0, 0, 0, 1/3, 1/3,
              1/3, 0, 1/3, 0, 0, 0, 1/3,
              0, 1/3, 0, 1/3, 0, 0, 1/3,
              0, 0, 1/3, 0, 1/3, 0, 1/3,
              0, 0, 0, 1/3, 0, 1/3, 1/3,
              1/3, 0, 0, 0, 1/3, 0, 1/3,
              rep(1/6, times = 6), 0), nrow = 7, ncol = 7, byrow = TRUE)`

Does this look correct or have I gone wrong?
For reference, to check it is diagonisable I used the R code

`P <- matrix(c(eigen(P1)$vectors), nrow = 7)
Pinv <- solve(P)
D <- diag(eigen(P1)$values)
P%*%D%*%Pinv`

Thanks in advance for any pointers you can give, I have only just started on this topic and I am a bit of a novice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the R language, but your transition matrix appears to be
$$
P=\pmatrix{0&\frac{1}{3}&0&0&0&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{3}&0&\frac{1}{3}& 0&0&0& \frac{1}{3}\\
0&\frac{1}{3}&0&\frac{1}{3}& 0&0& \frac{1}{3}\\
0&0&\frac{1}{3}&0&\frac{1}{3}& 0&\frac{1}{3}\\
0&0&0&\frac{1}{3}&0&\frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{3}&0&0&0&\frac{1}{3}&0&\frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{6}& \frac{1}{6}& \frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{6}&0
}\ ,
$$
which is correct.  This matrix *is* diagonalizable.  Its characteristic polynomial is $\ (x-1)\left(x+\frac{2}{3}\right)\left(x-\frac{1}{3}\right)^2\left(x+\frac{1}{3}\right)^3\ $, and the geometric multiplicity of each eigenvalue (i.e. the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace) is the same as its algebraic multiplicity (i.e multiplicity one for $1$ and $\ -\frac{2}{3}$, multiplicity two for $\frac{1}{3}$, and multiplicity $3$ for $\ -\frac{1}{3}$.  You can write down one eigenvector straight away—$\ \pmatrix{1&1&1&1&1&1&1}^\top\ $ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$—, and then complete a basis of eigenvectors by finding bases for the nullspaces of $\ P-\lambda I\ $ for each of the other eigenvalues $\ \lambda\ $.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and the amount of detail you included, must be an R code problem rather than the mathemtaics involved. Greatly appreciated!